# Чем открыть и проверить файл с почтовыми данными?

Tags: email, настройки

Переустановил виндовс с 7и на 10у и попутно сменил версию почты с outlook 2007-outlook 2010. Перемещал данные, через родной импорт\экспорт. Все удачно, но перестали приходить входящие, и письма помещаются в исходящие, но не числятся отправленными..
Мне просмотреть файл ost в outlook или разбираться в кешировании иных настройках? Если да, то в каких? Думаю еще удалить файл и синхронизироваться с почтой..хотя этот совет дан для outlook экспресс.

Answer (score 0):

Да. Все верно вы подметили. Вам надо проверить галочку в настройках кеширования.
Так же порекомендую почитать темы на сайте майкрософт:

Способы устранения проблем синхронизации, при синхронизации почтового ящика

- Exchange Server с OST-файла в Outlook [НАЖАТЬ](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/842284/how-to-troubleshoot-synchronization-problems-when-you-synchronize-your)
- Где находится
  автономный файл данных Outlook (OST)? [НАЖАТЬ](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-Outlook-e7b2e7b2-fb87-406c-85c7-04d4b69cf9a0)

По поводу синхронизации. На сколько я знаю у вас должна быть учетка там, и там.
То есть на outlook и outlook ексчендж.
- Что касаемо просмотра и открытия файла могу порекомендовать [НАЖАТЬ](https://www.convertost2pstfile.com/ru/)
Если у вас нет учетки ексчендж и с автономным файлом ничего не получиться, пробуйте поменять формат на локальный файл. как вариант через менеджер импорта.